# Serial communication c++ SerialPort-Class

Tags: c++, serial-port

First of all - I'm a student from Germany, so please excuse my bad english.
At the moment, I'm working on a Project which target is to controll servo Motors on an arduino board by Serial communication through xbee modules.
So now I'm studying the `SerialPort` but got Problems by using the `write()`.

My plan is to send integer values seperated by a commata through my Serial Port.
Visual Studio Reports an error and says that there is no Argument type that fits.
I really don't know how to handle this problem, because I'm completely new to this whole programming topic.

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#using <System.dll>;

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO::Ports;
using namespace System::Threading;

int main() {
    unsigned char values[2] = { 50, 120 };
    SerialPort^ mySerialPort = gcnew SerialPort("COM3");
        mySerialPort->BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort->Open();
while (true) {

            mySerialPort->Write(values);

    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you switch to C# rather than Managed C++ (aka C++/CLI aka C++/CX), and C# is more forgiving to newcomers. The first error I see is that you are opening your port EVERY time through the loop but aren't closing it or waiting for anything in the loop.

Comment: You are passing an unmanaged array[] to a .NET method that requires an `array<Byte>^`.  If you want "integer values separated by a comma" then you have to write a string, not an array of bytes.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for your help.
If I use a string instead of an Array, I just have to write

mySerialPort->Write("String"); right?
So there are just explicit values. How can I use strings to send, for example, something like "<value1,value2,value3>" which includes values that change every Iteration of my loop?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of type does the `^` syntax denote ? Is this valid c++ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO::Ports;
using namespace System::Threading;

int main() {
  // Managed array
  cli::array<unsigned char> ^values = { 50, 120 };
  SerialPort^ mySerialPort = gcnew SerialPort("COM3");
  mySerialPort->BaudRate = 9600;
  mySerialPort->Open();
  while (true) {

    // some work with values goes here...

    // We should specify buffer offset and length
    mySerialPort->Write(values, 0, values->Length);
  }
}
```

As you noticed, you can also send this data as string:

```
mySerialPort->WriteLine(String::Format("val1 = {0}; val2 = {1}", values[0], values[1]));
```

But be warned that `mySerialPort->Write()` sends *raw* bytes, and `mySerialPort->WriteLine()` sends each character as a single byte.
For instance:

```
cli::array<unsigned char> ^buffer = {123};

// Send one single byte 0x7b
mySerialPort->Write(buffer, 0, buffer->Length);

// Send 3 bytes (0x49, 0x50, 0x51)
mySerialPort->WriteLine(String::Format("{0}", buffer[0]));
```